# ubuntu 14.04 - hibernate resume failure after cloning system to other hard-drive

Tags: 14.04, boot, hibernate, resume

I've cloned my ubuntu to other hard-drive and it doesn't resume after hibernation. On my first hard drive it works fine. So, After hibernation instead of resuming, it starts normally, I lose everything what I left opened and when the desktop shows up it shows an error to send in a report.

**Do I have to change anything after moving system?** I only changed the swap partition UUID in /etc/fstab file and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and put the proper UUID in the file, like so:

```
sudo blkid # to determine the correct UUID for swap partition
gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
sudo update-initramfs -u
reboot
```

Contents of file:

```
RESUME=UUID=correct_UUID_here
```